# Очередь на Серова (=выставку Серова): A specific type of metonymy?

Tags: узус, терминология

I'm wondering, if anybody knows, what is this type called and if there are theoretical studies and/or monographies about contexts, in which these forms could  be particulary used (проходим Пушкина (=творчество Пушкина), играет Прокофьева (=пьесу Прокофьева), идем на Тарантино (=фильм Тарантино), билеты на Гришковца (=спектакль Гришковца)...

Comment: two tickets to the Rollings

Answer (score 9):

You are right. It's a metonymy. Here's an extract from the dictionary

> МЕТОНИМИЯ (переименование) (троп)– перенос названия с одного предмета на другой на основании их  смежности. Переименование может быть связано с заменой названия произведения именем автора:
>
> Читал охотно Апулея, а Цицерона не читал (А. Пушкин)

This kind of metonymy is called logical.

> Перенос имени автора на созданное им творение. Например:
>
> «перечитывать Пушкина» (книги Пушкина), «любить Шишкина» (картины Шишкина), «пользоваться Далем» (словарем под редакцией Даля).